# gitpython merge -X theirs

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to merge master into a local branch, while discarding anything conflicting, by choosing master, using gitpython.

I am doing

```
    repo = self._repo
    # have all history locally
    repo.git.fetch('--all')
    # set build branch as remote and discard local changes
    repo.git.reset('--hard', '{origin}/{branch}'
                   .format(origin=self.origin_name, branch=self.build_branch_name))

    # set active branch as build branch
    repo.git.checkout(self._config.git_branch)

    # merge master into build
    current = repo.active_branch
    master = repo.branches[self.master_name]
    base = repo.merge_base(current, master)
    repo.index.merge_tree(master, base, "-X theirs")
    repo.index.commit('Merge master into feature', parent_commits=(current.commit, master.commit))
```

this fails in `repo.index.merge_tree(master, base, "-X theirs")`
with `TypeError: merge_tree() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm trying to figure out the same thing, so these are essentially my notes while investigating...)

[`merge_tree`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/4a1339a3d6751b2e7c125aa3195bdc872d45a887/git/index/base.py#L216-L251) doesn't take any extra arguments other than `base`:

```py
    def merge_tree(self, rhs, base=None):
```

[The documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.index.base.IndexFile.merge_tree) says to use `index.from_tree` to control the merge resolution:

> Raises:
> GitCommandError – If there is a merge conflict. The error will be raised at the first conflicting path. If you want to have proper merge resolution to be done by yourself, you have to commit the changed index ( or make a valid tree from it ) and retry with a three-way IndexFile.from_tree call.

[`from_tree`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/4a1339a3d6751b2e7c125aa3195bdc872d45a887/git/index/base.py#L277-L345) takes extra arguments via `**kwargs` and passes them to its `git read-tree` command:

```py
    def from_tree(cls, repo, *treeish, **kwargs):
```

...

```py
            repo.git.read_tree(*arg_list, **kwargs)
```

However, [`read-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) doesn't have a merge stategy option; instead it just has `--trivial` and `--aggressive` (and `from_tree` uses `--aggressive` by default):

```
git read-tree [[-m [--trivial] [--aggressive] | --reset | --prefix=<prefix>]
        [-u [--exclude-per-directory=<gitignore>] | -i]]
        [--index-output=<file>] [--no-sparse-checkout]
        (--empty | <tree-ish1> [<tree-ish2> [<tree-ish3>]])
```

`from_tree` returns a new index rather than manipulating the global one, so my best guess as to what to do in your case is:

```py
    new_index = IndexFile.from_tree(repo, base, current, master, m=True)
    new_index.commit('Merge master into feature', parent_commits=(current.commit, master.commit))
```

At this point I'm not sure how you associate that new commit with your branch. [The gitpython team recommends](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/748#issuecomment-394659397) just using `repo.git.merge` anyway:

> However, my recommendation would always be to use the `git` command directly for such common functionality (like `repo.git.merge(...)`) unless you really have to implement your own specialized logic and thus go down to the plumbing with anything on `IndexFile`.

So maybe this instead:

```py
    repo.git.merge(master, X='theirs')
```